# Java Performance optimise replacing one String with another, repeatedly

Tags: java, html, string, performance, optimization

Im working on a HttpServlet extension (plugin) to a CMS, and its task is to filter the HTML response.

In my `filterResponse` method I get the requested `text/html` in a String, which is one of three parameters there.

Specifically what I need to do is to search the html String for a specific URL pattern and modify it slightly. Now, this can be a heavy operation when there are many links in a large document, and I want to optimise this process as much as possible.

My first version simply used the `replace("://www.", "://www-x1.")` method on the String.

Then, in the current version I use the `Matcher` and `Pattern` classes.
Example code:

```
@Override
public String filterResponse(HttpServletRequest request, String textHtml, String contentType) throws Exception {

   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("://www.");

   Matcher m = pattern.matcher(textHtml);
   String response = m.replaceAll("://www-x1.");

   .....
   .....

   return response;
}
```

In the real-world code I pre-compile the patterns (Pattern) in static fields and do the same with strings that are matched against.

Any ideas on how to make this faster? 
Perhaps convert to DOM object or some other XML object for faster query methods? Etc.

Comment: I think for a single replacement (i.e. one search-string, one replacement), this is close to optimal. If you do this repeatedly with different strings, there are definitely ways to optimize it. Converting to DOM (and back) is unlikely to be faster.

Comment: How do you compare the performance of your solutions? What fast is your first approach compared to your second? I would have guessed that the first simple approach is the fastest one..

Comment: Do not compile your pattern every time you enter this func. Do it once outside.

Comment: @Artur I do. Changed my wording at the bottom to make it clearer

Comment: @ThomasUhrig  I haven't done much work there yet. I want to hear from people with more expertise to see if I absolutely should do it in another way, or avoid my current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you use pattern matching where you don’t have a *pattern*. This is not only wasting performance, it is an error. For `"://www."` used as a pattern the last dot matches *any character*.

If you want to replace a simple `String` rather than a pattern, you can use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of `String.replaceAll`. This fixes the error and saves the entire overhead of creating a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` internally.

If you want to use the regex matcher, the simplest fix is to use `Pattern.compile("://www.", Pattern.LITERAL)` to stop interpreting special characters and allow using the Boyer–Moore algorithm for the entire sequence. This, however, will only pay off if you can store and re-use the prepared pattern.

Further, the `replaceAll` method offers the feature of interpreting back-references to groups of the match in the replacement `String`. Since you’re not using this feature, you can save the overhead associated with that feature by implementing the replacement loop by yourself. As a bonus you can use `StringBuilder` where the `Matcher` uses `StringBuffer`, but that’s only a minor improvement.

```
static String replace(String source)
{// the pattern would be better off being re-usable stored in a static field
  final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("://www.", Pattern.LITERAL);
  final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(source);
  boolean result = m.find();
  if (result) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.length()+16);
      int p=0;
      do {
        sb.append(source, p, m.start()).append("://www-x1.");
        p=m.end();
      } while (m.find());
      sb.append(source, p, source.length());
      return sb.toString();
  }
  return source;
}
```

But as already said, not using regex at all might be the better choice for this simple case here.

Comment: I saw afterwards, that you referred to `replace` rather than `replaceAll` in your question. But were you aware of the difference? Moving from `replace` to regex is not a natural choice…

Comment: I have no clue about the difference in overhead, I must admit. So you would recommend using the simplest solution, which is the String `replace` method? Or is the difference marginal? I do declare the Pattern objects as static final fields.

Comment: I would stay at the simplest solution, `String.replace`. The pattern example of my answer would pay off for larger search strings only, but `"://www."` is rather short. If in doubt, benchmark both variants.

Comment: Great responses, thanks! :) I will leave the question open for a little while longer and see if I get more good suggestions.

Comment: In this post here it is said that String `replace()` is implemented with regex also. And that Apache StringUtils `replace()` is implemented with `indexOf` and StringBuffer, and thus should be faster. What do you think?

Comment: That’s implementation dependent. But you can be sure that the internal implementation takes care of the fact that no *pattern* matching and no group references in the replacement are intended, e.g. by providing the flags I mentioned in the answer. It would rather be a proof that you can’t optimize such operations further as even the simple `replace` uses the sophisticated tools in the background. The current versions of regex use the Boyer–Moore algorithm for literal text search which is faster than `indexOf`.

Comment: I still would decide (and recommend) for either simply use `String.replace` or use a precompiled pattern which is remembered between the search operations. I would never use a third-party library for just using `indexOf`.

Comment: Cheers :) I also removed `contains(..)` checks as a condition to do `replace()`, which also improved the performance a bit. No need to run through the html documents twice.